# Trying to measure touch duration in android

Tags: android, imagebutton, duration

Is there a way to measure a touch duration of an ImmageButton in android?
I'm building an app that needs to use this data but all I've found was ensuring minimal duration

Answer (score 1):

you should use `setOnTouchListener` 
here you go

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   //start calculate your time here 
                     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```